# Which municipality/district near Berlin has a shorter Naturalization duration

Tags: germany, citizenship, passport, bureaucracy

Between Oberhavel, Havelland, and Postdam, or other municipalities around Berlin, which one has a shorter Einburgerung process according to your information.

The reason I ask: I have recently made a Naturalization application 1 month ago in Bayern and am about to Move to Berlin in 2 months. And after I do the anmeldung my application will also be forwarded to the Berlin office.

This appears quite hopeless to me since in Berlin my request will not be even looked at before the end of this year due to the centralization of the Einburgerung office in Berlin. Let alone normal cases, Berlin also has a significantly durable process on this topic compared to other cities, and can take years instead of months.

So I am thinking about moving to near Berlin instead of inside it. For example somewhere in Havelland, Oberhavel, or Postdam municipalities that are closer to my work. In general, if you had any loophole that you could suggest, I'd be gratefull.

Comment: Probably your Einbürgerungstest will become invalid since it has some land-specific questions.

Comment: @AndreySapegin it wont, since I already asked them